# Strip ajax response from ASCII? signs

Tags: javascript, ajax

Playing with API (https://quotesondesign.com/api-v4-0/) but got problem with properly format received string.

Looks like this: `Communication that doesn&#8217;t take a chance doesn&#8217;t stand a chance.`

Original response comes with `<p> tag` which I managed to strip by regex expression.

Code example: https://codepen.io/grimlok/pen/ppOKyZ/

Comment: Please post the code in the question, not a link, and create a [MCVE].

Comment: So that's (apparently valid) HTML, which you're then parsing with a regular expression. Is the question how to convert from HTML to plain text?

Comment: What has ASCII to do with JS/AJAX ..?

Comment: @Teemu ASCII has somehow become synonym for "hexadecimal" in popular culture. (And, for extension, "code" or "number" ;-)

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Yeah, it's a generic multipurpose initialism, just like JSON, both are almost always misused, though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Strip HTML from Text JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822452/strip-html-from-text-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those parts (`&#8217;`) are HTML Entities. If you want to decode them you can use a function like that:

```
function decodeHtml(html) {
    var txt = document.createElement("textarea");
    txt.innerHTML = html;
    return txt.value;
}
```

Add this function to your script and write

```
quoteData = decodeHtml(quoteData);
```

above your

```
console.log(quoteData);
```

---

<kbd>**[Working Codepen Demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OzoEEQ)**</kbd>